# Qt 4.8.4 built from source on Ubuntu 12.04 not working properly

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-12.04

I have tried for some time now to build Qt example [systray](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/desktop-systray.html). Everything works fine if I build it with Qt from official ubuntu repositoy.

Now I'm trying to build it using Qt 4.8.4 which is built from source. In this case, tray icons wont appear in system tray.

I have followed instructions on official Qt pages (requirements for X11 platforms, installation instructions), looked for possible solutions on qt web pages, ubuntu forums, stackoverflow, etc. but with no luck.

To compile and install Qt I made following steps:
1) installed suggested required packages 
2) downloaded Qt 4.8.4 from offiacial web 
3) configured with

```
./configure -release -nomake demos,examples,docs -no-webkit -no-script -no-scripttools -no-qt3support
```

4) installed with

```
make
sudo make install
```

5) added bin dir to PATH

Problem probably is not in built libs because if I copy them to another Ubuntu PC (not virtual machine) the example program works. I have only tried this with one non-virtual machine so I cant confirm if this may be the cause of problem.

I have tried this procedure on several virtual machines but with no luck. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try to configure `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` too?

Comment: Yes, I did but the result is the same. Maybe it is worth mentioning, that notification message is not located in its default location (top right corner, under the system tray) but in top letf corner (as if global system settings were ignored)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu provides `sni-qt` package and patched Qt so you can use `QSystemTrayIcon` class from Qt with notification area in Unity (see http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~indicator-applet-developers/sni-qt/trunk.13.04/view/head:/README).

You'll need to patch Qt source code before building it or use other desktop environment -- possibly you could just use other panel that provides classic tray area.

Comment: Thank you for this info. I was really starting to be desperate. Just one more thing. How can I find patches applied to ubuntu packages?

Comment: I can only find this: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~indicator-applet-developers/sni-qt/trunk.13.04/files/head:/patches/